# How can I put my css after tapestry css?

Tags: tapestry

I write tapestry application where I should put my css after tapestry css.

I added in my tapestry page correspondent java file the following lines of code:

```
@Import(stylesheet="http:/localhost:8080/ui-resources/css/styles.css?in_root=0")
void afterRender() {
}
```

and it is working fine. My problem is that I should give relative path to the css and not full url like it is now.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS docs at https://tapestry.apache.org/css.html describe how to use the @Import annotation with relative URLs to CSS files within your web app:

@Import(stylesheet="context:css/styles.css")

If the CSS file is outside your web app but under the same domain, try something like this:

@Import(stylesheet="/ui-resources/css/styles.css")

or put a style tag with a similar URL within your template (.tml) file.